# What are the values (coefficients) of a Gaussian Kernel?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, scipy.ndimage

A Gaussian filter can be applied to an image using the following commands:

1. `cv.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX[, dst[, sigmaY[, borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT]]] )`

For Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(50, step=2).reshape((5,5)).astype('uint8')
print(a)
J1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(a,ksize=(3,3), sigmaX =1, sigmaY=1, 
borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
print(J1)
```

The Answer is:

```
[[ 2  4  6  7  6]
[ 8 12 14 16 13]
[15 22 24 26 20]
[22 32 34 36 27]
[20 28 29 31 23]]
```

2. `from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter`
   `gaussian_filter(a, sigma=1,mode='constant',cval=0)`

For Example, My Code is:

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
gaussian_filter(a, sigma=1,mode='constant',cval=0)
```

The answer is:

```
 array([[ 2,  3,  5,  6,  5],
   [ 6,  9, 12, 14, 11],
   [13, 19, 22, 23, 18],
   [19, 26, 29, 29, 23],
   [17, 23, 26, 26, 19]])
```

3. We can create our filter using the equation $G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, and then apply this filer on an image using `cv2.filter2D` command.

For Example, My Code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,3), np.linspace(-1,1,3))
d = x**2 + y**2
sigma, mu = 1.0, 0.0
K = (1/(2*np.pi*sigma**2))*np.exp(- d / ( 2.0 * sigma**2 ) ) 
J2 = cv2.filter2D(a,-1,K, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
print(J2)
```

The answer is:

```
[[ 2  3  4  6  5]
[ 6  9 11 12 10]
[12 17 19 20 15]
[17 25 27 28 21]
[15 22 23 24 18]]
```

The answers to all these methods are different, so my question is that what kernel values (coefficients) are used for the filter.

Comment: I think providing concrete examples (with image and parameters) may help with this question.

Comment: The results of your three points should be (more or less) the same. Please give your code for #3, and parameter values for #1, so we can see what you did. Also share how the results differ.

Comment: Could you please edit your question a little, so the question is easier to understand? Thanks!

Comment: Your first problem is that you’re creating a Gaussian with sigma=1 in a 3x3 kernel. This makes no sense. https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the filter coefficients like this: Create a zeros matrix (or image), such as 20x20 or more, and set one pixel in the center to 1.0. Make a filter this matrix and print the result. The result will be equal to the coefficients of the filter. See "point spread function (**PSF**)" in wiki.